# What would prevent me from modifying my LDAP schema?

Tags: ldap, openldap, schema

I am trying to follow this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/kerberos-ldap.html) to configure kerberos on my Ubuntu server. I got up the part where they want to add the new schema to my server user `ldapadd` I follow the instructions as they say.

I run `ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W -f /tmp/cn=kerberos.ldif`

then I enter my password and it returns

`ldap_add: Invalid credentials (49)`

so I tried using the admin login that I use for my phpldapadmin webgui (which I thought was the same)

I run `ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=solignis,dc=local" -W -f /tmp/cn=kerberos.ldif`

then I enter my password and it returns this time

`ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)`

I am not really sure where to go from here I am still learning the ropes a bit. I have checked, double checked and triple checked I am entering the password that I set at install.

What am I not doing correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your config database. Without it, its trying to add it to your normal database.

```
ldapadd -H 'ldaps://localhost/cn=config' -x -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W -f /tmp/cn=kerberos.ldif
```